# How to load implementation with ctags in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

For browsing C++ code when I use ctags in vim, it jumps to the defintion. Sometimes I want to actually go to the implementation. I know I could tabnew or e the file. But I would just like to do that with Ctrl + ] and Ctrl + t. Is there any way to browse straight to the implementation like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your talking about is this:

```
:map <C-\> :tab split<CR> :exe 'tj' expand('<cword>')<CR>
```

This opens a new tab with the implementation when you press `ctrl - \`

I think I got this from Stack overflow actually but I don't have the source